# How could I recreate a PHP mail script in ASP?

Tags: asp.net, ajax

I'm trying to create a simple, completely stand-alone ASP script that reads GET variables posted from a jQuery ajax call and then sends an email based on some of those values. However, I am completely new to ASP and having some trouble converting it.

From my research, it appears that the ASP equivalent of $_GET['var_name'] is Request.QueryString['var_name']. However, with sending an email, I have stumbled across dozens and dozens of examples using everything from ASPEmail, CDOSYS, IPWorksMail, JMail, and so on. I have tried a few and I tend to get no positive results.

Here is what I'm trying to accomplish in ASP, written in PHP:

```
<?php
  if($_GET['val1'] != "") {
    // Add section one to the email.
  }

  if($_GET['val2'] != "") {
    // Add section two to the email
  }

  $email_company = mail($_GET['company_email'], $subject, $message, $headers);
  $email_client = mail($_GET['client_email'], $subject, $message, $headers);

  if($email_company && $email_client) {
    echo 'success';
  }
  else {
    echo 'error';
  }

?>
```

So, what should I be looking to use for emails? Can I made this page standalone, so that it can sit by itself and receive AJAX calls? Thank you for your time.

EDIT:

I have been trying stuff like this and I without fail get a 500 server error. I cannot view any error messages as all I get is a 500 page, so I don't know where to look for the problem.

```
<%=


' Create the Mail Message
Dim Mail As New MailMessage

' Set the address information
Mail.From = New MailAddress("from@website.com") 
Mail.To.Add("to@website.com")

' Set the content of the email
Mail.Subject = "Testing Email"
Mail.Body = "Hello, I am a test email!"

' Send the message
Dim SMTP As New SmtpClient("MAIL SERVER")
SMTP.EnableSsl = False
SMTP.Credentials = New System.Net.NetworkCredential("USERNAME", "PASSSWORD")
SMTP.Port = 25

SMTP.Send(Mail)



%>
```

Comment: For .NET it's as simple as using [SmtpClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient.aspx) to send mail (but it's not always the best). For ASP.NET it's as trivial as using PageMethods or WebMethods to deal with AJAX.

Comment: @user. Sorry about that. I was not sure which to choose. As I said, I am new to ASP as a whole. Also, I will look up Page Methods and see what I find. Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example using a standalone page and a webmethod. If you're still having problems, it could be an issue with your web server configuration. If you're using IIS, make sure you've set up the page in either a virtual directory or an application inside of a website with the proper bindings. Try making a simple html page at the location to make sure the page is reachable (and "where" you think it is).

Cheers.

```
 <%@ Page Language="C#" %>


<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>

    $(function () {

        var params = {};
        params['from'] = 'fake@test.com'
        params['to'] = 'fakeone@test.com;faketwo@test.com';
        params['body'] = 'hello world';       

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'default.aspx/SendMail',
            data: JSON.stringify(params),
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            dataType: "json"
        });
    });
</script>

<script runat="server">


    [System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
    public static void SendMail(string to, string from, string body) 
    {

        var mail = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage();
        mail.Body = body;
        mail.From = new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress(from);
        foreach (var r in to.Split(';'))
            mail.To.Add(r);

        var smtp = new System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient("mail.yourdomain.com");

        smtp.Send(mail);

    }

</script>
```

Comment: Used your example as a basis for building my own script. Thank you very much.